# ng-zorro-mobile support for Angular 14 & Angular 15?

Tags: angular14, ng-zorro-antd, ng-zorro-mobile

the latest version ng-zorro-mobile 6.0.0 does not work with Angular 14 & 15 because of:

```
./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd-mobile/fesm2020/ng-zorro-antd-mobile.mjs:4451:13-27 - Error: export 'ɵɵresetView' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationInitStatus, ApplicationModule, ApplicationRef, Attribute, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_S...
```

When will the newest Angular versions 14 and 15 be supported?
Can be done something now to make it work on Angular 14 and 15?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

for all I know, supporting for ng14 will be done in the next two weeks.